# Assigning to a Reference Inside a Struct

Tags: c++98

I created a struct with a reference to a vector and I'm having problems assigning to it after I created an array of structs.

This is my struct:

```
struct name{
        std::vector<Student> &A;
        int a;
        int b;
};
```

In my main, I have created a vector of class type, Student, and I have assigned values to the vector, which I called StudentVector. I'm trying to declare an array of struct name that contains a reference to my vector, StudentVector:

```
void main(){

std::vector <Student> StudentVector;

....

....

....

name data[5];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++){


           data[i].A = StudentVector;

}
```

When I do this, it compiles, but I get a segmentation fault when I run my code.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not compile, because there is no way how to initialize the reference 'A'. If you really need to do it this way, replace the reference with a pointer:

```
struct name {
    std::vector<Student> *A;
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::vector<Student> StudentVector;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i].A = &StudentVector;
}
```

But it would be wise to avoid it completely.

Comment: Thank you so much!